# How to delete clip-path mask from image object in canvas using fabricJS?

Tags: fabricjs, dispose, clip-path

I am working in one image editing tool in which i need one functionality of image clipping mask.

I am using fabric js latest version.

I have put one toggle button for clip image into circle. and want to toggle it from circle to square(or other fix shape) and square(or other fix shape) to circle.

So I think , when toggle button is on then i clip my image with circle.

But i don't know how to remove that clip mask if toggle button is off.

Is there any way to remove that clip-Path mask from image object in fabric js.

Scenario look like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

on your click event, try:

```
YourImage.clipPath = null
```

Comment: Could you format your code? You can do that by indenting the code with 4 spaces.